# how to calculate bytes length of rsa keys if modulus length is known

Tags: cryptography, rsa, cryptojs

I use nodeJS crypto for my project. I need a way to find out the real length of the public key and private key in bytes knowing their `modulusLength`. For example, if you generate a pair of keys with 1024 bit modulusLength, length of private key will be 610 bytes

Comment: *if you generate a pair of keys with 1024 bit modulusLength, length of private key will be 610 bytes*, no, that likely is not true. It very much depends on how the private key is represented but in most such representations (like PKCS8) the length will vary. You can compute the mean and variance of the length however. And, if it were ever important, we could probably create keypairs whose private keys in a certain format were always of a specified length.

Comment: The minimum static size of an RSA private key is about 2 times the key size in bytes (the modulus and private exponent as unsigned integers), but you would not get any speedup because the CRT parameters would be missing. For the public key you would need precisely the key size, because if you assume that 65537 is the public exponent - this is commonly the case - then you just need the modulus. There is one other trick: safe the seed from which the key pair is generated for the private key. Then you just need 128 bits, but if any part of the key pair generation changes you're out of luck.